# Is there a way to run Cypress tests online?

Tags: cypress

We need to run the Cypress tests online, such that navigating to a URL in web should run all the tests.

The UI don't have to be same as Cypress localhost UI. All we want is, different people involving the project should be able to run these tests from anywhere.

Comment: You can run them in a CI environment and expose that online.  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html

Comment: With CI, I can only run tests by running "cypress run" right. Is there any option to run the tests.. like for example, clicking on "run tests" button on any browesr should run the tests.